# Request to reopen "how to handle c# as if it was homoiconic language?"

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

I have severely edited [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472310/how-to-handle-c-sharp-as-if-it-was-homoiconic-language-was-getting-list-of-all) so it can meet the guidelines, how can it get reopened?

Comment: You are still asking for a tool/framework, right?

Comment: @rene : if there is anything else besides those I still would like to know, yes I suppose.

Comment: *I have severely edited* is a little bit overstated. I think the nature of your question hasn't changed. Also, as indicated by @JonSkeet in his comments on your question, it's still unclear what you are trying to achieve and what problem you want to solve. Please note that asking *specific* questions works best for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Arjang I'm sorry but that makes it off-topic. You could ask a question that demonstrates why the obvious approach doesn't work for you and that might produce answers that recommend a library.

Comment: Why not just use reflection, as JS suggests? It's relatively trivial.  You should have some kind of goal which isn't solved by the most obvious route, and be able to describe the situation within the question.  Or it might just be navel gazing.

Comment: @will : that question is using the concrete example of a more general form. It was meant to be a general question not just that specific case, but the guide lines require the questions not to be too general, so it was a naïve attempt to make the question specific in some form or another.

Comment: So, you just wanted a list of different ways?  Yeah, we don't really do Lists of Things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Editing the question will have put it on the Reopen Review queue.

There, users with >3,000 reputation can view it, check your edits and vote to reopen if they think that it's been salvaged.